# Plotting a 2D graph in Octave: getting nonconformant arguments error with graph not coming correctly

Tags: octave

I'm making a graph out of calculations by putting energy over the overall distance traveled. I used the equation E/D = F (Energy/Distance = Force) to try and got values in order to create a 2D line graph from them. However, I'm getting errors such as "nonconformant arguments", one of my variables being randomly turned to 0 and that the vector lengths aren't matching, here's the code:

```
% Declaring all the variables for the drag equation
p = 1.23;
v = 0:30;
C = 0.32;
A = 3.61;
D = 100000;

% This next line of code uses the variables above in order to get the force.
Fd = (p*(v.^2)*C*A)/2

% This force is then used to calculate the energy used to overcome the drag force
E = Fd*D
kWh = (E/3.6e+6);
Dist = (D/1000);

x = 0:Dist
y = 0:kWh

plot(x,y)
xlabel('x, Distance( km )')
ylabel('y, Energy Used Per Hour ( kWh )')
```

The outputs:

[image: the graph]

[image: the command window]

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Your question is not about C, C++ nor MATLAB, so don't add those tags. Also, please read [mre]. Unless you give some example values for `p`, `v`, `C` and `A`, we cannot reproduce your issues and therefore have a much harder time understanding what the problem might be.

Comment: No problem I'll make the changes

Comment: If `kWh` is less than 1, then `0:KWh` will be `0`. What are you trying to plot?

Comment: A straight line graph basically showing how the energy and distance (kWh, D) is proportional with the gradient (Drag Force) staying constant.

Comment: You could `plot(v,kWh)`. `Dist` is a single value, not a series like `v` is, so it doesn't make sense to try to plot against it.

Comment: That's true actually, I did try to do that but now the output is "x = 0 and y = 0"

Comment: My code: https://gyazo.com/2f8d965e3a369f1c3875b6fdfd527c59

Comment: Yeah, don't do `y=0:kWh` and so on. Just do `plot(v,kWh)`.